# Java String: Recursion solution for Split long Sting to fixed length smaller parts and combine them

Tags: java, string, recursion

According to UI component requirement, with the use of long String value I have to populate fixed length smaller String values and combine them.

```
Ex:-  long String value: AAABBBCCDEEEFFGGGG

      Fixed length smaller String value: AAA
                                         BBB
                                         CCD
                                         EEE
                                         FFG
                                         GGG
```

For make this enable I have write some utility method as follow. 
I want to know, as a optimise solution whether it can write some recursion method ? Thanks.

```
/**
 * @param fullLongString Long String value
 * @param maxLengthOfPart Maximum length of the smaller String 
 * @return String result as a short String
 */
public static String getShortString(String fullLongString, int maxLengthOfPart) {

    if((fullLongString == null) || (fullLongString.trim().equals("")) || (maxLengthOfPart <= 0) || (fullLongString.length() <= maxLengthOfPart)) {
        return fullLongString;
    }

    StringBuilder fullShortString = new StringBuilder();
    int numberOfStringParts = fullLongString.length() / maxLengthOfPart;

    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = maxLengthOfPart;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStringParts; i++) {

        String smallPart = fullLongString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

        if(i == 0) {
            fullShortString.append(smallPart);
        } else {
            fullShortString.append("\n").append(smallPart);
        }

        startIndex = endIndex;
        endIndex += maxLengthOfPart;
    }

    String remainPart = fullLongString.substring((endIndex - maxLengthOfPart), (fullLongString.length()));

    if((remainPart != null) && (!remainPart.trim().equals(""))) {
        fullShortString.append("\n").append(remainPart);
    }

    return fullShortString.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. If your code works - why do you want to re-write it using recursion?

Comment: Or maybe try posting it in Code Review if you want some help on optimizing it.

Comment: alfasin - I need to make optimize it with recursion ,  J.Lucky - Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me. Recursion saves a lot of code.

```
/**
 * @param fullLongString Long String value
 * @param maxLengthOfPart Maximum length of the smaller String 
 * @return String result as a short String
 */
public static String getShortString(String fullLongString, int maxLengthOfPart) {

    if((fullLongString == null) || (fullLongString.trim().equals("")) || (maxLengthOfPart <= 0) || (fullLongString.length() <= maxLengthOfPart)) {
        return fullLongString;
    } else {
       String firstPart = fullLongString.substring(0, maxLengthOfPart);
       return firstPart + "\n" + getShortString(fullLongString.substring(maxLengthOfPart, fullLongString.length()),maxLengthOfPart);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I recommend the Guava library which comes with a [`Splitter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) and a [`Joiner`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class.

**Usage**:

```
public static String splitEqual(String strand, int width) {
    return Joiner.on('\n').join(Splitter.fixedLength(width).trimResults().split(strand));
}
```